# How can I display installed apps in a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I've searched Google but haven't found anything relating to this.

I'm using Android Studio to create my first Material App. Now I want to display all the apps installed on my phone inside a RecyclerView. Is this possible?

Comment: Use `PackageManager` to get information about installed apps, and use that as the model data for your `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model to save the package information:

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    public getAppName(){
       return appname;
       }
    }
```

CustomAdapter to set the value of the application name, you can also display the icons etc by adding additional code. By invoking the getInstalledApps will return you PInfo class object using which you can the package information. It takes one parameter, pass true if you want to get the system apps else send false(code reference from this [site](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon))

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.Viewhold> {
ArrayList<PInfo> appn;
    public CustomAdapter() {
       appn=p.getInstalledApps(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

          return appn.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Viewhold holder, int pos) {
      for(int i=0;i<appn.size();i++{
          holder.appname.setText(appn.get(i).pname);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
   }


private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
        ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
        final int max = apps.size();
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
            apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
        }
        return apps;
    }

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
  public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView appname;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        appname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.appname);
    }
   }
}
```

**yourlayout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Just invoke the adapter as below in your mainactivity:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Visit the site to learn about Recyclerview http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. Your help is much appreciated! Quick question, should I have a mainactivity to invoke the adapter and also have a separate activity for the PInfo class and CustomAdapter class?

Comment: Yes its better to have them in separate files...however its possible to have them in same file

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it surely helped. But I want this list to be Alphabetically sorted, can someone help me with that?